# CSS - Input-Rule for all Browsers`?

Tags: css

I added to every textarea, every textfield and every button a special class. I have many buttons and many textfields on my page so i decide to clean my code.

I delete all the special classes like (.textarea), (.textfield) and (.button) in the html code. Over 180 hits ... so my code is shorter now.

I add the three new rules into the CSS  -> input.button , input.text, textarea

But was this a good idea? Coz it dont work on every browser -.-

Is there a better method (rule) like -> input.button , input.text, textarea ? Or should i use my first solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS, use input followed by a type attribute check.  For example, to apply a rule to text boxes and textareas, you'd use:

```
input[type="text"], textarea
```

To apply a style to buttons, you'd use:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"]
```

This works in all browsers that I've tested with (IE6+, Firefox, Chrome, & Safari).

Answer (score 0):

IE7+ allows you to use the attribute in your CSS selectors ala `input[type='text']` usage shares on IE6 are between 11-17% depending on where you look, so this might be an option. Otherwise adding a class to each shouldn't be causing too many problems.  This question might help [CSS Selector for <input type="?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470702/css-selector-for-input-type)

for more info on support of different CSS selectors check out http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html