# Can I style an input button to be just a rectangle with a border?

Tags: css

I would like to style my input buttons to take away all the normal styling and just make them into rectangles with rounded edges. I'm new to CSS. Can someone tell me if it's possible to do this.

John

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yea, sure.

```
input[type=submit], input[type=button], button {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #f00;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

There you go.

http://jsfiddle.net/4fW4y/

Example with more bells and whistles:

http://jsfiddle.net/4fW4y/1/

And yea, as Jeroen noted, the fancier effects are supported only in modern browsers.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Note that the rounded edges may not be supported in older browsers (IE6? not sure).

Comment: Also be aware that input selectors [may not be supported in IE6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470702/css-selector-for-input-type)