# custom different submit button in same css

Tags: html, css

Can I customize different submit button in the same css ? For example I would like a search image in search button but a normal submit for the sign-up page . Is is possible ?

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195632/how-to-change-an-input-button-image-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

In CSS its not possible to put condition like that but you can create two diffrent claases for that or you can make use of javascript/jquery to change image.

Comment: IMO Using different classes/ids and styling based on them than using Javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Submit buttons are a *type* of buttons. By default a `<input type="button">` or a `<button>` is a, well, button.

You can have a separate class for submit buttons and "normal" buttons (IE7+)

```
input[type=button]
input[type=submit]
button
button[type=submit]
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470702/css-selector-for-input-type) for more details

You can also have different `id`s:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
<button id="searchButton">Search</button>
```

And css

```
#submitButton
{
}

#searchButton
{
}
```

or `class`es

```
<button type="submit" class="submitButton">Submit</button>
<button class="searchButton">Search</button>
```

And css

```
.submitButton
{
}

.searchButton
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do that.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><title>Title Here </title>
</head><body>
<style type="text/css">input[type=submit] {    padding:5px 15px;     background:#cccfe0;     color: #fff;    border:0 none;    cursor:pointer;    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;    border-radius: 5px; }.ButtonA {background-color:333E7B;border-radius:5px;border:5px solid #B7D96B;box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;color:#8576AD;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;height:32px;text-shadow:#E04644 0 1px 0background: FFD700;padding:4px 16px;text-decoration: none;}.ButtonA:hover{color: FDE47F;background: 7CCCE5;}.ButtonB {background-color:2E8B57;border-radius:5px;border:5px solid #6B8E23;box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;color:#BDB76B;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;height:32px;text-shadow:#3CB371 0 1px 0background: FFD700;padding:4px 16px;text-decoration: none;}.ButtonB:hover{color: 32CD32;background: FFFF00;}.ButtonC {background-color:5F9EA0;border-radius:5px;border:5px solid #008B8B;box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;color:#7FFFD4;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;height:32px;text-shadow:#5F9EA0 0 1px 0background: FFD700;padding:4px 16px;text-decoration: none;}.ButtonC:hover{color: 66CDAA;background: 008080;}.submit input     {     color: #000;     background: #ffa20f;     border: 2px outset #d7b9c9     } </style>

New Test Here
<button class="ButtonA" type="submit" name="Button" id="hiddenField" value="010000"> Admon  </button>&nbsp;
<button class="ButtonB" type="submit" name="Button" id="hiddenField" value="020000"> Reports</button>&nbsp;
<button class="ButtonC" type="submit" name="Button" id="hiddenField" value="030000"> Data   </button>&nbsp;
<table border="1"><form action="001_CrudScreen.py" method="post"></form>


</table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite hard to understand, but if I'm reading you correctly, what you want is to have two buttons which share the same basic styling, but which have some styling elements that are different?

In that case, the answer is yes, it's quite simple.

The easiest way is to give them multiple classes. So you would give them both the same class, which specifies the styles you want them to share, but also a secondary class name which styles the additional features. You can also use the ID or name instead of a second class.

```
<input type='button' id='signup-button' class='mybutton' value='Sign Up' />
<input type='button' id='search-button' class='mybutton' value='Search' />

.mybutton {
    /*shared styles go here*/
}

#signup-button {
   /*specific signup button styles here/*
}

#search-button {
   /*specific search button styles here/*
}
```

There's a number of other ways you can differentiate them in CSS, but that's probably the easiest.

Hope that helps.