# I am seeking help for CSS trick

Tags: css

I have a little CSS code as below:

```
input{
    background-image:url(css_img/input_bg.gif);
    padding:6px;
    margin:1px;
    width:250px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-variant:normal;
    height:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 3px #DDDDDD;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    color:#333333;
}
```

But this code changes the style of all the `<input type="..."/>` tags. How can I change the style of just text fields `<input type="text" name="name" />`? I don't want to have to add classes to them.

Also is there any way to round the corner just using plain CSS (not using image) which diplays well in **Internet Explorer.**

Please help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
input[type="text"] {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: Is this correct? input[type="submit"]{
 background-image:url(css_img/ahfrwwh24u6.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 border:#CCC 0px solid;
 padding:4px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:12px;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
}

Comment: Why don't you add class name to element?

Comment: @Indian Girl: Which version of internet explorer are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use an attribute selector:

```
input[type="text"] { styles here }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eric and Rikudo stated :

```
input[type="text"]
```

For the corners in ie use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

You can also use :

```
input[type=text]
input[type^=te]
input[type$=ex]
input[type*=t]
```

Element input with attribute type which contains a value that is equal to, begins with, ends with or contains a certain value.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470702/css-selector-for-input-type/470778#470778)

Comment: I am using two CSS like above. One is input[type="text"]{..code..} and other is input[type="submit"]{..code..} But still not working On Internet Explorer only ? why. My CSS is on an externel css file

Comment: `input[type$=ex]` won't work. With `$=` you are trying to search end of word `ex` but inside `input type='text'` you should write `$='xt'`.