# The correct selector for all radio buttons Css

Tags: html, css

Is this the correct way to style radio buttons in CSS ?

```
input [type = radio] {

<!-- Css stuff -->

}
```

Comment: @Xufox thanks, what about the space within the square brackets.

Comment: Those probably don’t make a difference, but I’d still remove them, just to be sure.

Comment: The proper way is with quotations: input[type="radio"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Selector for <input type="?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470702/css-selector-for-input-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the spaces. They have meaning in CSS - something like "all elements within". So, your selector is performing an extra function that you don't want. It should be: `input[type="radio"]` instead.

Also, "correct" can have many meanings. For example, it might make more sense for you to change your HTML to `<input type="radio" class="radio-btn">` and then use `.radio-btn` in your CSS, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.

```
input[type="radio"] {

}
```

With

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {

}
```

to style the selected version of it. You need to remove the space between `input` and `[type = radio]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=radio]
{
  /*all styles here applied here*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
input[type="radio"]
```

Don't forget the quotes